# I want to find primes $p$ where $p-1$ is smooth

Tags: discrete-mathematics, cryptography

I'm using the Pollard's $p-1$ method but for some numbers this method won't work.

For example for: $n = 436916347656251$.

$$n - 1 = 2 \times 5^{10} \times 7^5 \times 11^3$$

But Pollard's algorithm return failure.

Does anyone know how can I find that numbers?

Comment: Hello, can I ask what is "smooth"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number

Comment: I want to primes p with 128 bits, i need a efficient algorithm.

Comment: An efficient algorithm for finding large primes $q$--nevermind whether $q-1$ is smooth or not--is not yet known, this is standard in the literature.

Comment: How smooth do you want $p-1$ to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a technique that will perhaps give satisfactory results. It's not clear (to me) from your post what exactly your requirements are.

I would start with a smooth number, $s$ (you can generate this by multiplying powers of small primes together--including at least one power of $2$). Then check, using say the Miller-Rabin test, whether $s+1$ is (a probable) prime.  If so, take $p=s+1$.

The reason I think this method is better than trying to factor $p-1$ (for prime $p$) is that smooth numbers are generally rarer than primes.

I tried automating this process with Python to find several large primes, $p$ with $p-1$ being smooth.  For instance, the probable prime $p=14567951311943370063315833900714950657$ has $p-1=2^{87}\cdot 3^{23}$.

Comment: Oh, can you share your code? Thank you so much

Comment: Really the main thing is the Miller-Rabin probabilistic primality test, information for which you can find on line, including You Tube videos on ways you might code it.